# What was the Ludicrous Patents Office?

Tags: harry-potter, laws, ministry-of-magic

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, one of the departments in the Ministry of Magic referred to is the "Ludicrous Patents Office".

> “Level seven, Department of Magical Games and Sports, incorporating the British and Irish Quidditch League Headquarters, Official Gobstones Club, and **Ludicrous Patents Office**.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - Chapter Seven)</sub>

### What is the Ludicrous Patents Office? What does it do? Do we have any other uses of it in canon? Does the Ministry really need an office devoted to wacky ideas?

Rowling-canon is preferred, but other answers are still welcome.

Comment: If you invent something ludicrous, where do you go?

Comment: @Valorum - Does *ludicrous* have a different connotation in British English?

Comment: The English word "ludicrous" comes from the Latin word for "play", and its oldest meaning (according to the OED) is "pertaining to play or sport". That sense of the word is obsolete in muggledom, but maybe it's still used in the wizarding world? Presumably the Ludicrous Patents Office is where you get a patent on sporting equipment.

Comment: [It's satire of gov bureaucracy](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=830765)

Comment: "Does the Ministry really need an office devoted to wacky ideas?" - I thought that *was* the Ministry...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## We don't know...

It appears to be an office in the Ministry of Magic, but nobody knows what it actually *does* in canon. As far as I know (I searched), JKR has not said anything about this.

The name could be an Easter Egg, and the office deals with patenting 'ludicrous' things.

## What is most likely

As @user14111 mentioned in the comments, the word comes from the Latin word for 'play', and its oldest know usage is as 'pertaining to play or sport'. So perhaps, since it's located in the Department of Magical Games and Sports, this is where you get patents on magical sports equipment.

From [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ludicrous) (emphasis mine):

> 1610s, **"pertaining to play or sport"** (a sense now obsolete), from Latin ludicrus "sportive" (source of Old French ludicre), from ludicrum "amusement, game, toy, source of amusement, joke," from ludere "to play."

It doesn't mean 'ludicrous' in the modern sense. It's the place where you go to patent new magical things related to Games and Sports.

Comment: I suspect that the first name of "Ludo Bagman" was chosen because of its meaning in Latin, so JKR is likely aware of this connotation of "ludicrous".